# How to merge various partitions on a disk into a single one ? (without data loss)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, dynamic-disk

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1, alongside Windows 10. I have a single HDD on which I want to do this. This HDD is a dynamic disk with 4 partitions, one The system reserved, one with the OS installed and other two for data storage. According to the internet tutorials on how to do this, I first created an unallocated space out of my OS partition, booted with the Win 8.1 DVD and then when I select the unallocated space Windows installer prompts me that "This disk contains one or more dynamic volumes...". So I learned that I will have to convert the dynamic disk to basic. I had a copy of MiniTool partition manager, so I opened it up and selected the "Convert Dynamic Disk To Basic" option, but then the partition manager prompts that it can only convert dynamic disks with "A SINGLE PARTITION". Now my question is how do I merge all my partitions into one without any data loss and not disturbing my present Windows 10 installation.

**If any other workaround is possible please inform me that too, as I want to install the Windows 8.1 alongside my Win 10 with minimum hassle.**

Here are some screenshots for reference.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It has been a while, but I believe the windows Disk manager can convert it back to a basic partition scheme without requiring to delete or recreate any partition.

Comment: @LPChip really! can you guide me through the procedure.

Comment: Uh... you just right click on the part where it says Disk 0, and then choose Convert to Basic. Can't miss really.

Comment: @LPChip, I don't know why, but that option is greyed out. 

Comment: Ah, okay... that sucks. Yeah, it has been a while since I played with this. May come to making a full backup, delete all partitions, then recreate everything.

Comment: @LPChip that's why I came here, to find a way to get things done while avoiding backing up, deleting partitions and starting everything again from scratch.

Comment: @LPChip Let that pass, I was asking is there any other way I can dual boot Windows 8.1 alongside my Win 10 with less hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk Management doesn't allow people to convert a dynamic disk to basic if it has volumes already. minitool doesn't allow you to convert because your E: is composed of 3 parts. Under this situation, you need to copy volume E: to another drive with minitool's copy volume feature, or transfer data from E: to another disk with Windows copy & paste function, then delete E: and convert to basic disk.